# Error on ACM conference template on TeXworks!

Tags: titles, acm, acmart

I've downloaded the LaTex template from [this link](https://ipsn.acm.org/2020/submission.html?v=1). While compiling the LaTex file (`sample-sigconf.tex`), I get the following error:
[image]

I haven't modified any lines in the template file, still, I get the error. Is there anything wrong with the template file or with my PC? What could be the solution to this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was occurred due to the following lines:

```
%% A "teaser" image appears between the author and affiliation
%% information and the body of the document, and typically spans the
%% page.
%\begin{teaserfigure}
 % \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{sampleteaser}
  %\caption{Seattle Mariners at Spring Training, 2010.}
  %\Description{Enjoying the baseball game from the third-base
  %seats. Ichiro Suzuki preparing to bat.}
  %\label{fig:teaser}
%\end{teaserfigure}
```

There are some other instructions for `Tables` and `Equations`too. We need to comment on them with `%` or delete those lines from the Tex file. If you see further lines on the Tex file, you can find the proper Tex code for `Figure`, `Table`, and `Equations`.

After removing the error-prone 'instructions', my problem was solved.